How to space between capitalised letter in mysql 8.0+ version
Hi I have column of FullName - RamSingh, NehaKaur etc etc and I want to write a select statement which return Ram Singh, Neha Kaur etc etc in MySql 8.0+ version. Also, what if there are 3 capitalised letter name like RamSinghRathore
I tried a lot of query like
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(CAST('JohnLexxxanon' as BINARY), '^([A-Z][a-z]+)([A-Z][a-z]+)$', '$1 $2');

but it did not work

MySQL REGEXP_REPLACE doesn't provide a way to refer to capture groups, so I don't think you can do this directly. Do it in the presentation code in your application.

@Barmar, Yes, MySQL 8.0 uses $1, $2, ... to reference captured groups. I don't find it mentioned in the manual, but it works.

That's why we love MySQL :)

please do give the exact result of select version();, not just "8.0+"

@BillKarwin this query has worked great SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('JohnLexxxanon' COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_as_cs,
'^([[:upper:]][[:lower:]]+)([[:upper:]][[:lower:]]+ but what If we have some names like SureshSinghRathore, then how would we handle this?

What about Irish ("O'Henry") and Dutch ("van der Something"), and probably others.

It is usually best to cleanse the data as it is being Inserted.

does the following help ?
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('ThisHasMultipleUpperCaseWords' COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_as_cs ,'([A-Z])',' $1');
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| REGEXP_REPLACE('ThisHasMultipleUpperCaseWords' COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_as_cs ,'([A-Z])',' $1') |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  This Has Multiple Upper Case Words                                                         |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

As others have mentioned, 'cleansing' before it gets inserted may be preferable.

This is superhelpful mate<3 thank you so much @ticktalk
